# Double precision default 0 not null

Tags: sql, oracle, precision, create-table

when creating a table, the following column_definition has been used. Can somebody explain what is the meaning of the first column definition?

```
Create Table abc_TEMP (column_1 DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0 Not Null,
....);
```

Comment: What part do you not understand?  It actually seems rather self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a [DOUBLE PRECISION](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljdoubleprecision.html) datatype column called `column_1` (it's a floating-point number with binary precision 126).

This column doesn't accept null values explicitly, but if you omit it on an `INSERT` statement, the number 0 will be set to it.

Comment: Thanks Diego for your explanation. It certainly helps. Can you further explain the concept of 'binary precision 126'?

Comment: The DOUBLE PRECISION is the ANSI to the FLOAT(p) Oracle data type. 
For NUMBER data types: precision p = Number of Digits.
For FLOAT data types: precision p = Binary Precision (multiply by 0.30103 to convert).

So FLOAT = FLOAT (126) = 126 x 0.30103 = approx 37.9 digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `COLUMN_1` should store values that are floating-point numbers with a binary precision of 126 bits.  So, if someone tries to put a string or a date into this field, they should get an error.  That's what `DOUBLE PRECISION` means.

It also means that if someone inserts a row into the table and does not specify a value for `COLUMN_1`, Oracle should just default in a value of zero on that row.  That is what `DEFAULT 0` means.

It also means that if someone explicitly tries to set the value of `COLUMN_1` to NULL, they should not be allowed and they should get an error.  That is what `NOT NULL` means.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your explanation. It certainly helps. Can you further explain the concept of 'binary precision 126'?

Comment: Yes, it means that it cannot store a number that cannot be represented internally by 126 bits.  For example, you cannot store the value of pi out to a billion digits.